# Primefaces: Menuitem (or button) does not work in Internet Explorer after update

Tags: primefaces

I am experiencing some weird behavior with menu items on updated components. My sample JSF page looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head/>
<h:body>

  <h:form id="form">

    <p:menubar id="menubar" widgetVar="menubar">
      <p:menuitem value="Select me" onclick="alert('Menu item selected')"/>
    </p:menubar>

    <p:commandButton value="Update menubar" update="menubar"/>

  </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

When I run this in Internet Explorer 11 and click on "Update menubar", the menu item no longer functions, i.e. the alert is not displayed, and the URL in the address bar changes from ..../test.xhtml to ..../test.xhtml#.

When I run the same with Firefox, everything works nicely, i.e. even after an update of the menubar via a button click, the menu item still displays the alert.

Is this behavior an IE bug? Or is it supposed to work that way? Is there a workaround for the IE behavior?

---

**Edit:**

The problematic sample can be further reduced; the same problem arises in a form that consist solely of two buttons, with one updating the other, causing it to stop working in IE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head/>
<h:body>

  <h:form id="form">

    <p:commandButton value="Click me" onclick="alert('Button clicked')"
                     id="button" widgetVar="button"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Update button" update="button"/>

  </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after further investigation it appears that the problem is caused by missing access rights in my IE installation - somehow the AJAX response involved in the update does not get handled correctly (even though no corresponding error messages or log entries are shown).
So, luckily, nothing's wrong with Primefaces here :)